# Zend Framework Doctrine insert one-to-many

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

Amongst order tables i have a Customers table and Addresses table. A customer can have many addresses so I have setup a one-to-many relationship in a yaml file. The thing is the id for the Customers table is auto generated so I would not know the Customers_id until after the insert however, the Customers_id is a foreign key in the Addresses table.

The information for both tables is captured on the same form although each set of data is in a subform. How do I get Doctrine to insert the data into the Customers table then fetch the Customers_id just entered and use it as the foreign key for the Addresses table.

Hope I have been able to get the essence of the question across.

BTW I am using Zend Framework and Doctrine 1.2.3

Comment: Doesn't Doctrine auto populate the object's ID property when the insert is flushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do $customer->save(), you may use $customer->id (if "id" is the Customers_id column name of your customer table) to get the Customers_id to put in Addresses table.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do $customer->save(); the following statement $customer->identifier(); should give you the id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Doctrine 1.x you could do the following:

```
$cusomer->Address[] = $address; // Assign multiple addresses in this manner
$customer->save();
```

This will first save the customer details to the db and then store the address data. Since doctrine understands the relationship between customer and address, the ORM will insert the customer id in the address table. Further this will be run within a transaction by Doctrine which ensures that if one of the operations fail the entire transaction will be rolled back.